# How can I prevent entering 2 time record with the same employee after pressing time-in button

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have this code:

```
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO timelogTB (EmpNo, Time_In, Date_)" & _
                "VALUES (@EmpNo, @Time_In, @Date_)"

            Dim date1 As Date
            date1 = New Date(dtpTime.Value.Ticks - (dtpTime.Value.Ticks Mod TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond))

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpNo", comboxEmpno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Time_In", date1))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Date_", dtpDate.Value.Date))

            Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            If rowsAffected > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Record save successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Congratulations")
                comboxEmpno.Text = ""
                txtLname.Text = ""
                txtFname.Text = ""
                txtMname.Text = ""
                txtPosition.Text = ""
                txtEmpstat.Text = ""

            Else
                MsgBox("Error saving record!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Unsuccessful")
            End If
```

Let's say employee # 101 clicks the time-in button, it'll record the time and date.

Then he accidentally clicks the time-in button again and again records a new time.

I want to show a message box saying that "This user has already time-in" something like that.

Comment: Write some SQL to test whether the employee already has a time in row for that day.

Comment: Can you give me some code on how should do it. I am new in vb.net

Comment: Do you know how you'd do it if you did it directly in SQL? I.e. get the count on the number of rows for given empNo for given date?

Comment: I don't know how to do it also.

Comment: You need to get up to speed on the basics then https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to elaborate your scenario more for proper solution. Do the tables stores the time logs per day per employee OR its just the 1 time log record per day or just 1st record per table? Assuming time logs per day per employee is what your scenario may be, below are my suggestions:-

1. Update the table and if it fails you can insert a new row. This will preserve only 1 row per day for that employee. Update query will be

   cmd.CommandText = "Update timelogTB Set Time_In=@Time_In Where EmpNo = " & @EmpNo & " AND Date_ = '" & Format(@Date_, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "';"
2. Check the count of the rows before inserting (this is same as suggested by @Andrew Mortimer). 
   Note: Below is the code updated using notepad so please excuse me if you find any syntax mistakes.

   ```
   conn.Open()
   ```

   Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand

   ```
   count = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(Time_In) AS timelogTB FROM timelogTB WHERE EmpNo = " & @EmpNo & " AND Date_ = '" & Format(@Date_, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "';"

   Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

   If count > 0 Then
      'do not insert new record, exit from the function
      'this depends on your implementation, you may prefer to use Else also.
      MsgBox("Record already inserted!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
      Return
   End If

   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO timelogTB (EmpNo, Time_In, Date_)" & _
       "VALUES (@EmpNo, @Time_In, @Date_)"

   Dim date1 As Date
   date1 = New Date(dtpTime.Value.Ticks - (dtpTime.Value.Ticks Mod TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond))

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpNo", comboxEmpno.Text)
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Time_In", date1))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Date_", dtpDate.Value.Date))

   Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

   If rowsAffected > 0 Then
       MsgBox("Record save successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Congratulations")
       comboxEmpno.Text = ""
       txtLname.Text = ""
       txtFname.Text = ""
       txtMname.Text = ""
       txtPosition.Text = ""
       txtEmpstat.Text = ""
   Else
       MsgBox("Error saving record!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Unsuccessful")
   End If
   ```
3. If your scenario is based on per session the form/application is run, you may disable the time-in button after record is inserted.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I will try this code and I'll get back to you.

Comment: by the way the scenario was your first guess. the employee will time-in per day.

Comment: sir the code also prevents the to time-in the next day and the message does show up. it was just not saving that's all. How should I fix it?

Comment: Check 3 things. 1. Put a break point at cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(Time_In).... and copy the query in the variable cmd.CommandText. 2. Run this query in DB and check the count of rows. 3. Do F10 and then see the count of rows returned from DB. This will give you clue for next step. Or let me know the result will guide you accordingly.